# Check for required properties with behat on POST

Tags: behat, gherkin

I'm testing my REST API so I'm doing something like this:

```gherkin
Scenario: Create a Task List
  Given I send a POST to tasklist with json:
  """
  {
    "creator_id" : 1,
    "title" : "Behat Test List",
    "display_order" : 7,
    "color" : 123456,
    "type": 1
  }
  """
  Then The response code should be 201
```

Those 5 properties are all required in order to create a task list.  I now need to write five more of these and leave off one of the parameters and make sure the response code is a 400 instead.  That feels like a ton of duplication.  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try scenario outline like this:

```
Scenario Outline: Create a Task List
Given I send a POST to tasklist with json:
"""<sample>"""
Then The response code should be 201

Examples:
  | sample                                                                                              |
  | { "creator_id" : 1, "title" : "Behat Test List", "display_order" : 7, "color" : 123456, "type": 1 } |
```